# Entity Framework no statements executed after query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

So i'm using Quartz to create a task scheduler for my program and I'm having issues where if there are multiple jobs to run, it will repeatedly execute the query for the respective job but then never exectues the very next line.  It's as if it hangs as soon as i hit tolist().  Any ideas?

```
try
{
    //work on query further , need to get client ID correctly
    if (vehicleses.Count == 0)
        return null;
    string siteId = QueryExportSiteWithId(exportSiteId).SiteId;
    string clientId = vehicleses[0].ClientID;
    db.Database.Log = Console.Write;


    var inventoryyReturn = from i in db.Inventory_Vehicles
        where dealerIdList.Any(c => c == i.ClientID) && i.Archived != "1" && i.Holding != "1" &&
              i.Status == "A"
        select i;

    var inventoryDescription = from i in db.Inventory_Descriptions
        where
        inventoryyReturn.Any(
            c => new {client = c.ClientID, inv = c.ID} == new {client = i.ClientID, inv = i.InventoryID})
        select i;
    var settingsExports = from i in db.Settings_Exports
        where inventoryyReturn.Any(c => c.ClientID == i.ClientID)
        select i;
    var settingLots = from i in db.Settings_Lots
        where
        inventoryyReturn.Any(
            c => new {client = c.ClientID, lot = c.LotID} == new {client = i.ClientID, lot = i.ID})
        select i;
    var inventoryFeatures = from i in db.Inventory_Features
        where
        inventoryyReturn.Any(
            c => new {client = c.ClientID, inv = c.ID} == new {client = i.ClientID, inv = i.InventoryID})
        select i;
    var inventoryPhotos = from i in db.Inventory_Photos
        where
        inventoryyReturn.Any(c => c.ID == i.InventoryID)
        select i;


    var longReturnListt = (from i in inventoryyReturn
        join l in inventoryDescription on new {inv = i.ID, cli = i.ClientID} equals
        new {inv = l.InventoryID, cli = l.ClientID} into descGroup
        from m in descGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join s in settingsExports on i.ClientID equals s.ClientID into settingGroup
        from sg in settingGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join sl in settingLots on new {client = sg.ClientID, lot = sg.LotID} equals
        new {client = sl.ClientID, lot = sl.ID} into lotsGroup
        from lg in lotsGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join se in db.Settings_ExportSites on new {client = lg.ClientID, lotId = i.LotID, site = siteId}
        equals new {client = se.ClientID, lotId = se.LotID, site = se.Site} into exportGroup
        from eg in exportGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join f in inventoryFeatures on new {inv = i.ID, cli = i.ClientID} equals
        new {inv = f.InventoryID, cli = f.ClientID} into invFeatGroup
        from ifg in invFeatGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join p in inventoryPhotos on i.ID equals p.InventoryID into photo
        from photos in photo.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                    orderby i.ID
        select new {i, m, sg, photoo = photo.ToList(), lg, ifg, eg}
        into grouped

        group grouped by new {grouped.i.ClientID}
        into groupedDone
        //select groupedDone

        from categories in groupedDone
        select new NewType
        {
            InventoryVehicles = categories.i,
            InventoryDescriptions = categories.m,
            SettingsExports = categories.sg,
            InventoryPhotos = categories.photoo,
            SettingsLots = categories.lg,
            InventoryFeatures = categories.ifg,
            SettingsExportSites = categories.eg
        }
    ).ToList();
  //  var sql = ((System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery) longReturnListt as ObjectQuery);
 //   var trace = sql.ToTraceString();

    if (longReturnListt != null)
    {
        //returnList.AddRange(longReturnListt.);
        return returnList;
    }
    return null;
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception);
    throw;
}
```

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but it seems like this behavior could be caused by a circular join reference.

Comment: First, there is no need to post basically one and the same question several times. Second, joining to all these subqueries with `Any` inside makes no any sense, just join to their corresponding `DbSet`s, or better use navigation properties.